# Ministro 2 : Invalid Qt Version

Tags: android, qt, android-sdk, qtcreator

В случае использования конфигурации сборки с `Ministro`:

`Ministro` что-то скачивает на 2.8 Mb.

Затем, приложение выдаёт сообщение об ошибке :

> Invalid Qt Version

В Play Store  массовые отзывы по этой проблеме.

Функционирует ли вообще данная возможность?

С какой версией она работала крайний раз?

Софт свежайший:

Ministro_2 10.6

Qt 5.9.1 android_armeabi_v7a_GCC4.9

NDK .r15

anroid sdk : 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В 5.8 и 5.9 ministro не работает, поскольку не создана соответствующая репа с библиотеками. Тем не менее, судя по описанию проблемы у вас путь к старой репе указан в проекте, это лучше поправить:
проверьте libs.xml (в папке android/res/values если шаблоны были экспортированы или в /5.9/android_armv7/src/android/templates/res/values/libs.xml если не были)
Там должно быть:

```
<array name="qt_sources">
<item>https://download.qt.io/ministro/android/qt5/qt-5.9</item>
</array>
```

Проблема, скорее всего, вызвана тем, что проект был создан на другой версии Qt и были экспортированы шаблоны. Начиная с версии 5.9 экспорт шаблонов выполняется не копированием файлов, а ссылками из gradle-скрипта, советую переехать на этот механизм, иначе придется руками обновлять файлы всегда при переезде на новую версию Qt

Comment: я, собственно, не знаю как оно было раньше так-как начал писать под андроид с qt5.9.

Answer (score 0):

> В 5.8 и 5.9 ministro не работает, поскольку не создана соответствующая
>   репа с библиотеками

последний доступный url c дистрибутивами:
https://download.qt.io/ministro/android/qt5/qt-5.7/
../qt-5.8/ ../qt-5.9/ ссылок не существует.

Похоже в Qt решили прекратить раздачу. Теперь каждый должен заботится о репозитарии самостоятельно.